# How to parse data from a no-name array json using jq in linux command?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

```json
[
  {
    "id": 4738245,
    "project_id": 25486,
    "sha": "871c0484c3a7e72deea96fbcd48djdgh2",
    "ref": "",
    "status": "success",
    "created_at": "2022-01-06T04:44:40.372Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-06T04:50:36.663Z",
    "web_url": ""
  }
]
```

The above is the json response I get from an gitlab API. I am trying to use `jq '.id'` to parse the id from the json response.

The error I get is :`jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "id"`

I understand that it should be `jq '.<arrayName> .id'` to parse it. However, the response does not give any arrayName so I cannot use that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the element `id` is nested within an object such like the other ones by wrapper curly braces, then call that as

```
jq '.[].id'
```

in order to get the value `4738245`